# jQuery using cloned data to filter table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some issues that I can't seem to track down.

Order of Operations:

1. PHP Renders Table to the page
2. jQuery Clones the table and stores it as a global variable
3. When a user clicks on the filter button, it appends the global variable to the DOM and removes rows that don't meet the filter criteria.
4. Somehow, this is impacting the global variable as when I go through the different filters, it eventually no longer appends data as if its removing the rows from the global variable I keep appending and manipulating.

My Table has rows like so:

```
<tr data-area-count="2" data-region-count="2" data-regions="North America, EMEA" data-areas="Area 1, Area 2">
```

My jQuery:

```
// Global Vars
var results,
    oTable;

$(function() {
  results = $('[name=resultsTable]').clone();
});
```

There are several buttons on the page a user can filter the data by. When they click on the button, this is the function that is run:

```
// Depending on which region needs to be shown, toggle here.
function filterRegion(region) {

var data = results,
    tempArray = Array(),
    tempAreas,
    tempRegions;


// Based on the region/option we selected..
switch (region) {
     case 'EMEA':

        // Append the data to the dom
        $('.res').empty().append(data).find('table').addClass('dt');

        // Loop over the rows
        $('.res').find('.results tr').each(function() {
            // Collect the values of each of the rows we interate over
            tempRegions = $(this).data('regions');
            tempArray = tempRegions.split(", ");
            tempRow = $(this);

            // Check to see if this case value exists in the array
            if (jQuery.inArray('EMEA', tempArray) == -1) {
                // the region is not in the array, remove the row
                tempRow.remove();
            };

        });

        break;
}
```

In the statement above, I expect it to append he original, untouched, version of the table that was initially loaded and then if `EMEA` was not in the list of `data-regions`, it would remove all of the rows from the table in the DOM.

However, it seems to be altering data in the global variable because when I toggle back between the different filters, I am eventually left with no data being appended to the DOM since its "removed" all the rows when hitting each of the filter statements.

I feel that I am cloning or using the cloned data incorrectly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but wouldn't it be way simpler to just hide filtered rows visually as opposed to removing them from the DOM?

Comment: Using Datatables and exporting the results was more of a headache to deal with the hiding so I figured I could just keep a fresh copy of the full data set and then append/manipulate it as needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the json append documentation (https://api.jquery.com/append/):

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned).

So I think in your `append(data)` call you move the data from your global result variable there. Then later you remove elements from it (which modifies the global results DOM object). Instead you have to clone it once again. So I think replacing the line

```
var data = results,
```

with

```
var data = results.clone(),
```

should solve the problem. I didn't test it though.

Comment: Damn, that simple huh? Worked just fine, that was driving me crazy!

Comment: @SBB you could still avoid the first cloning: `results = $('[name=resultsTable]');` then works on data cloned, if i'm correct. And last thing, you should clone event and data btw: `var data = results.clone(true),`